# DefaultIfEmpty() doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq

Hi i am trying to use `DefaultIfEmpty()` function on `IQueryable` and it's throwing an exception "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'DefaultIfEmpty'."
this is my code:

```
 Dinner defaultDinner = db.Dinners.Where(d => d.DinnerID == 5).Single();
 Dinner blah;
 IQueryable<Dinner> bla = db.Dinners.Where(d => d.DinnerID == id)
                            .DefaultIfEmpty(defaultDinner);
 blah = bla.First();
 return blah;
```

I found a different way to do it without `DefaultIfEmpty` but i still want to know how to solve this... here is the first part of the exception:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported overload used for query operator 'DefaultIfEmpty'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems pretty self-explanatory to me:

> Unsupported overload used for query operator 'DefaultIfEmpty'

Sounds like your LINQ provider (which you haven't specified) doesn't support the overload of `DefaultIfEmpty` which takes a default value.

The simplest alternative is probably to use:

```
var ret = db.Dinners.Where(d => d.DinnerID == id)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
return ret ?? db.Dinners.Where(d => d.DinnerID == 5).Single();
```

Note that this approach avoids fetching the "default" dinner unless it's required, so it's more efficient too.

(If there should only be a single result for any ID, you should probably use `SingleOrDefault` instead of `FirstOrDefault` by the way. It's more logical that way.)

Comment: I'm using: system.data.linq.table

Comment: *"It's more logical that way."* It also gives you proactive failures, if you're incorrect about there only possibly being one result at most. Prevented a bug for me just today. Thanks, Jon.

Answer (score 2):

Try out

```
Dinner dinner = db.Dinners.SingleOrDefault(d => d.DinnerID == id);
```

Comment: The problem here is that the ``Default`` returned by ``SingleOrDefault`` is the default value *for that type*.  In this case, since ``Dinner`` is a class, it would be ``null``.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : removed this already, I've mix up it with something can't recall exactly.. but somewhere I saw such syntax

Comment: On the edit: ``IEnumerable<Dinner> dinners = db.Dinners.Any(d => d.DinnerID == id);``  Won't compile.  ``Any`` returns a ``bool``, not an ``IEnumerable<T>``.

Comment: @John Skeet: found what I mean - DefaultIfEmpty.SingleOrDefault(), this was my initial thoughts

Answer (score 1):

The `DefaultIfEmpty` method throws a `NotSupportedException` when called on an `IQueryable<T>`.  You could perform an explicit cast to an `IEnumerable<T>` by calling `db.Dinners.Where(d => d.DinnerId == id).ToEnumerable().First()`.

You probably *shouldn't* use this method, though.  It's better to just check whether the call returned any values, and retrieve the default if it didn't.

**Edit**:  Oop.  Nope, Jon Skeet is correct.  The `DefaultIfEmpty` extension method relies on an implementation from the query provider, so it definitely depends on what query provider is being used.

Comment: Surely whether or not it throws an exception depends on the *implementation* of IQueryable<T>. There's nothing to stop it from handling that operator with no problems.

Comment: ``DefaultIfEmpty`` is an extension method in ``System.Linq``, it's not a member of the class implementing ``IQueryable<T>`` *or* ``IEnumerable<T>``.  So no, I don't see how the implementation would matter?

Comment: It's an extension method in Queryable, yes - which makes calls on the `IQueryable<T>` in the first parameter. The implementation does *very* much matter. For example, try `string y = new string[0].AsQueryable().DefaultIfEmpty("foo").First();` - that will succeed with no problems, despite still calling `Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty`.

Comment: Yep, you're right--checking the documentation for ``Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty``, it mentions that the actual behavior of the call is deferred to the query provider.